# How to deploy logstash with persistent volume on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, plugins, logstash, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-pvc

Using GKE to deploy logstash by statefulset kind with pvc. Also need to install an output plugin.

When don't use `while true; do sleep 1000; done;` in container's command `args`, it can't deploy with pvc successfully.

The pod will cause `CrashLoopBackOff` error.

```
  Normal   Created                 13s (x2 over 14s)  kubelet                  Created container logstash
  Normal   Started                 13s (x2 over 13s)  kubelet                  Started container logstash
  Warning  BackOff                 11s (x2 over 12s)  kubelet                  Back-off restarting failed container
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40093356/14718202) I found it can try to add sleep. So the statefulset with pvc can deploy successfully.

But when check its logs will find:

```
/bin/sh: bin/logstash-plugin: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: bin/logstash: No such file or directory
```

How to do it in a good way to start container to install an logstash output plugin?

The whole manifest file:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: logstash-to-gcs
  namespace: logging
spec:
  serviceName: "logstash"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: logstash
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.10.0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 2Gi
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5044
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config
          - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
          - name: logstash-data
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
        args:
          - bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-google_cloud_storage;
            bin/logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf;
            while true; do sleep 1000; done;
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: logstash-configmap
            items:
              - key: logstash.yml
                path: logstash.yml
        - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
          configMap:
            name: logstash-configmap
            items:
              - key: logstash.conf
                path: logstash.conf
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: logstash-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

For my containers I have a script I have ran on Container Deployments and it works to install the plugins and then run logstash.
Post Arg> sh /usr/share/logstash/config/plugins.sh

```
#!binbash

echo running post install scripts for plugins..;
logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-sentimentalizer
logstash-plugin install logstash-input-mysql
echo finished post install scripts for plugins..;
sleep 1
exec logstash
```